# Could someone give my code for a deque a quick once over please?

Tags: java, deque

Been working on this for a while now and I think I've finally cracked it, it's working for all my tests, but I have a feeling there will be some niggling issues. This is a heavily simplified version of a double sided queue (deque) where every time a value is added, a temporary array is made to store all values, and then the new value appended on. It is easiest to explain this way, I believe. If someone could please just double-check I am correct and there is nothing glaringly wrong here, I would be extremely thankful. Thank you all very much ! :)

```
    public class ArrayBasedDeque<EltType> implements Deque<EltType> {

  private final int CAPACITY = 10;
  private int capacity;
  private int end;
  private EltType deque[];  

  public ArrayBasedDeque() {
    this.capacity = CAPACITY;
    deque = (EltType[]) (new Object[capacity]);  
  }
  public EltType first() {
    return  deque[0];
  }
  public EltType last() {
    return deque[end-1];
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return end == 0;
  }

  public int size() {
   return deque.length;
  }

  public boolean isFull() {
   return end == capacity;
  }
  public void insertFirst(EltType inserted) {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
    EltType[] tempArray;
    capacity+=1;
    tempArray = (EltType[]) new Object[capacity];
    for(int i=0;i<end;i++){
    tempArray[i+1] = deque[i]; 
    }
    deque=tempArray;
    }
    deque[0] = inserted;
    end++;
    }

  public void insertLast(EltType last) {
    if (isFull()){
          EltType[] tempArray;
          capacity+=1;
      tempArray = (EltType[]) new Object[capacity];
      for (int i=0;i<end;i++) {
        tempArray[i] = deque[i]; 
      }
//      System.out.print(deque[end]);
    }
    deque[end] = last;   
    end++;
  }

  public EltType removeFirst() {
    EltType[] tempArray;
    EltType returned = deque[0];
    tempArray = (EltType[]) new Object[capacity];
      for (int i=1;i<capacity;i++) {
        tempArray[i-1] = deque[i]; 
      }
      deque = tempArray;
      end--;
    return returned;
  }

  public EltType removeLast() {
    EltType[] tempArray;
    EltType returned = deque[end-1];

    tempArray = (EltType[]) new Object[capacity];
      for (int i=0;i<capacity;i++) {
        tempArray[i] = deque[i]; 
      }
      deque = tempArray;
      end--;
    return returned;
  }




}
```

Comment: This might be better asked over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ahh, I have found a problem now, after many calls to abd.insertLast(5);, I get the message : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
 at ArrayBasedDeque.insertLast(ArrayBasedDeque.java:54). Can anyone see what is causing this ?

Comment: Deque actually stands for `Double Ended Queue` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few comments:

- I would use `T` or `E` as the name of the type parameter, rather than `EltType`
- I'd rename the constant `CAPACITY` to `DEFAULT_CAPACITY`, and make it static.
- `first()` will return a value even if the deque is logically empty
- `last()`, `removeLast()` and `removeFirst()` should throw an appropriate exception if `end` is 0
- There's no point in having a capacity separate from the size unless you're using that to avoid creating a new array each time. If you're *always* going to expand/shrink the array on any change, just use the array on its own - you can tell the size just from the array's length
- In `removeFirst` and `removeLast` your loop bound is `capacity` instead of `end`
- Use `System.arraycopy` as a simpler way to copy arrays
- You haven't got an assignment to `deque` in `insertLast` - hence the exception you're seeing in the comments.

I'm not sure I see the benefit of having this over just using `ArrayList<T>` though... the main point of having a separate `Deque` implementation would be to make adding to both head *and* tail cheap... here we have neither!

... or of course just use `ArrayDeque` or `LinkedList` :)

Comment: CAPACITY is not just the default, its the only initial capacity. If there was another constructor which allowed you to set the capacity this would be better all round.

Comment: @Jon, didn't notice that the inserts can increase the capacity by 1.

Comment: @Peter: But the `capacity` is still redundant, as it will always be 10 more than `end` - and could be taken from the array length anyway :)

Comment: +1: Wrapping ArrayList is by far the simplest way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

- don't create a new Object[] every time you add or remove an entry.
- Use System.arrayCopy() instead of manual copy.
- You don't need to copy up to the capacity, only up to the end.
- you could use a ring buffer to avoid needing to move elements around (no need for copies)
- Drop Based from the name ArrayDeque is more consistent with ArrayList, ArrayBlockingQueue, etc.